# Make waveform like Soundcoud Player with javascript/jQuery in html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, soundcloud

I want to make a audio player look like Soundcloud player with waveform made from mp3 file using javascript/jQuery and html5 canvas. I know that there is a lot of questions like mine on stackoverflow but no one can find a true answer...

[image: SoundCloud audio player]

---

I made this but it's not really nice.

```js
        var imgBg = new Image(),
            imgFg = new Image(),
            count = 2;
        imgBg.onload = imgFg.onload = init;
        imgBg.src = "http://www.filetolink.com/605b7afaa1";
        imgFg.src = "https://files.fm/thumb_show.php?i=5ddxxmmn";

        function init() {
          if (--count) return;   // makes sure both images are loaded
          
           var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas"),
               ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
               audio =  document.querySelector("audio");
          
          canvas.width = imgBg.naturalWidth;
          canvas.height = imgBg.naturalHeight;
          
          render();
          
          audio.volume = 0.5;
          audio.addEventListener("timeupdate", render);
          
          function render() {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.drawImage(imgBg, 0, 0);
            
            // calc progress
            var pst = audio.currentTime / audio.duration;
            
            // draw clipped version of top image
            if (pst > 0) {
              ctx.drawImage(imgFg, 0, 0, (canvas.width * pst)|0, canvas.height,  // source
                                   0, 0, (canvas.width * pst)|0, canvas.height); // dst
            }
          }
        }
```

```css
        body {background:#ccc}
        canvas {width:600px;height:auto; background:#CCCCCC}
```

```html
  <audio src="https://failiem.lv/down.php?i=puupmmqb" controls=""></audio>
  <canvas height="238" width="1470"></canvas>
```

I already found lot of script arround the web but no one look like soundcloud player.

List of links that i found on the web but not exactly like i'm searching for :

- https://github.com/AlexJuca/SpectrumVisualizer
- https://github.com/michaeldzjap/waveplayer.js?files=1
- https://github.com/katspaugh/wavesurfer.js

Thank to everyone who can help me and thank you for your advices.

Comment: Hi, try this: https://github.com/bbc/peaks.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do like soundcloud, don't forget that no matter how difficult it is you will just look like a copy.
Separate the two parts.
Build that player using waveform.
Secondly make you cursor look like a pointer, and wherever you clik you hook the fact that you can post a comment based on the percentage you are in the song.
Sorry as i'm french but thinking like this i think you are going to understand easier what you have to do !

Look at this : http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/audio-waveform-player-with-playlist/full_screen_preview/18420897?_ga=2.157064376.2056415136.1512709641-883454457.1511933135